# Invalid postback or callback argument

Tags: .net, postback, callback, modal-dialog, event-validation

This question seems to have been asked before, but I feel like my situation is slightly different.

I have a page that contains a gridview.  When a button is pressed to edit one of the records in the gridview, the button first executes some client script that pops up a modal window for the purposes of editing (set using .onClientClick).  From this pop-up, the user hits Update which updates the database and closes the window.  Once the window is closed, the button's server-side code is supposed to fire, which will call the function to refresh the gridview.  Instead, I get the error message:

> Invalid postback or callback argument.
>   Event validation is enabled using in
>   configuration or in a page. For
>   security purposes, this feature
>   verifies that arguments to postback or
>   callback events originate from the
>   server control that originally
>   rendered them. If the data is valid
>   and expected, use the
>   ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation
>   method in order to register the
>   postback or callback data for
>   validation.

What really irks me is that I use this exact same logic on a different page and it works fine.

Any suggestions as to how I could avoid this?

UPDATE:  I have removed the line of code that added the client-side script, and I still get the error.  So I'm fairly positive it is being caused simply by the postback.  Upon closer inspection I realize that there are in fact some ListItems being programatically bound to DropDownLists.  So... I probably need to do the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation thing.... Could someone possibly give me an example on what the syntax for doing that would look like?  Seems to be set up differently than the ScriptManager object....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your button is created in the code-behind (for example, your `RowDataBound` event creates a new instance of `Button` and adds it to a cell) then you will need to recreate those controls (with the same `ID`s) before the Control Events stage of the page life-cycle.  Recreating the buttons in the `Load` event should work fine.

If your controls are created and you've attached handlers to their events then the most probable cause of this error is javascript which modifies your DOM/form.

Comment: hmm, no the button (ImageButton) is defined in the .aspx

the 'onClientClick' is added in a RowDataBound... could that have something to do with it?

Comment: Is your Click handler attached in the markup or in the code-behind?  The Click event, not ClientClick.

Comment: in the markup:  <asp:ImageButton ID="btnAddTask" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Add.png" Title="Add New Task" onClick="btnRefresh_Click" />

Comment: Then its a safe bet that your problem lies somewhere in what your javascript is doing.  See womp's answer.  However, I'd advise against disabling event validation.  If you analyze the problem you should find the appropriate fix.

Comment: I think you're right....  There must be something else going on in JS that I'm unaware of...

Comment: Actually, I removed all client-side code from the button, and I still get the error (see UPDATE)

Answer (score 0):

This can be a tricky one to debug.  If you're not using dynamically generated controls, the biggest culprit is generally client side scripts modifying the data that the controls are bound to.  For example, adding another list item to a dropdownlist using javascript will trigger this error, as the server will notice that the added item was not part of the original data.

If you are using dynamic controls, you will have to ensure that the controls and their data are created the same way on every postback.

Whenever I run into irreconcilable event validation problems, I usually disable it on the page.  This is supposedly a security issue, but I have yet to see an exploit relying on event validation being turned off.  Actually, maybe I'll ask that on SO, to see if anyone knows of any.  It's easy to sanitize your page inputs, and should be done without even thinking about whether event validation will protect you or not.

Comment: Thanks for the response...  How would you suggest disabling event validation?  I put EnableViewStateMac="false" in the page directive, but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this line in the page directive, once I had a similar error and with this the error was solved

```
EnableEventValidation="false"
```

Regards!!!

Comment: This does work... But my boss wasn't willing to go this route.

Answer (score 0):

Event validation will try to ensure someone isn't adding values to the page that doesn't correspond to what is allowed when you processed/rendered it for the first time. Depending on the controls you have, if you are doing a full rebind of the gridview, and the underlying data changed, this can make the "valid values" on the page to not match those received in the post back.

An option, that depends on the scenario, is to not use a postback in that case but do a regular link to get the page refreshed. Alternatively you can do EnableEventValidation=false as has been suggested, but you need to make extra sure you are not relying in any values you sent to the client i.e. dropdowns can come with values not in the list you bound.

Comment: Could you extrapolate on how to refresh the page without a postback?  What type of control can do that?  Or do you mean that I should add in another button (ie 'refresh') that the user would click to refresh the grid on-demand?

Comment: @Matthew you can use an asp:HyperLink and give it the current's page Url. As I said it depends on the scenario, since it won't help if you are using controls outside the gridview to filter the list. It would be just as any other link that gets you to that page.

Answer (score 0):

Every time I run into this problem it is because I am using a client-side script to manipulate a server-side object.  This works find when the script is called from the server but when the client-side tries to run the script via post-back; it will pop the error.

Better off only using client-side objects with client-side scripts.

Answer (score -1):

I got this error when I created an ASP.Net WebForm, and clicked the Submit button.

The HTML had been created with a  tag nested within the  tag, and the browser saw the nested  tag as closing the ASP.Net form. As a result, the __EVENTVALIDATION hidden field was outside the form, and not sent to the server.

Cleaning the nested  tag from the markup resolved the problem.

I know your question has been resolved, but I hope this helps someone suffering similarly.